# CSS/Bootstrap for Page Layout

Tags: css, layout

I am needing assistance with building the layout of my code. I am new and trying to place images (with links) on top of a background image.

I can manually build each piece out but want to work on developing a template that I can just edit the photos and links I would use. I also need it to be responsive.

Looking for just some basics on how to create the layout. I know how to add images, video, and stuff like that just struggling building the containers the content would go in.

Max-width = 700 px
Mas-height = 600 px

[Result I am going For](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDa0a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems this will be your code structure:

```
// Main Page Div
<div class="container>
//Heading

//Next div for two container
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-lg-6">
//content
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-6">
//content
</div>
</div>

//Next div for three container
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-lg-4">
//content
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-4">
//content
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-4">
//content
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was thinking so this is reassuring that I  am on the right track. To the first two items (col 1 & col 2) to be on top of the purple banner do you know the best way to get that to happen?

Comment: The first is an image now but going to be replaced with an embedded video. The second is a navigation menu.